# Cannot access custom agent parameters

Tags: anylogic

I'm trying to make a traffic simulation model in Anylogic. I made a custom car agent (the_car) and it has two parameters. I cannot access the parameters of car agent in StopLine "On passed Car Action". It is showing the error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field the_car.parameter".

String i =  the_car.parameter; //the error is in this line.

Comment: Please add some more examples to your question, format the code and format your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell your process blocks that it is the_car type agents passing through. Likely, you use a CarSource object, set it up such that it creates not default "Agent" agents but your the_car agents.

Then, you need to understand how code fields work. They often have specific keywords that refer to functionality, see my [blog post](https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2016/2/4/the-magic-lightbulb-and-how-it-can-help-your-anylogic-modelling). You will need to write `String i = agent.parameter`